# Open a div element on a button click with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a `map` function inside the render function and upon a button click want to display the following div but I am unable to do. Earlier the `onClick` was triggered for the all the buttons inside the table of each row which ideally should not be the case.

Code :

```
const [list, setList] = useState(false)

 const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(e.target.value) {
            setList(!list)
        }
        setList(!list)
    }

return (

    <TableCell>
             <Button className = 'active-select-option'
               onClick = {handleClick}>Actions</Button>
            {list ?                                                
            <div className = "select-option">
               <ul id = 'action1' className = "select-option-inner rounded">
                 
                 <li>Buy More</li>
                 
                 <li>Sell </li> 
                
                 <li>Next Li Tag</li> 
                 <li>Edit Detials</li>
                </ul> 
              </div> :  ' ' }
       </TableCell> )
```

Comment: pls show handleClick function, and what is list?

Comment: Here List have added just to toggle the click

Comment: What is TableCell?
try to use div instead and it will work. So maybe the problem in it

Comment: TableCell is a component derived from the material Ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track the selected row id for displaying the action panel.

```
import "./styles.css";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1001,
    label: "Action1"
  },
  {
    id: 1002,
    label: "Action2"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setSelectedId(id !== selectedId ? id : null);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((val) => (
        <div>
          <TableCell>
            <Button
              className="active-select-option"
              onClick={() => handleClick(val.id)}
            >
              {val.label}
            </Button>
            {selectedId === val.id && (
              <div className="select-option">
                <ul id="action1" className="select-option-inner rounded">
                  <li>Buy More</li>

                  <li>Sell </li>

                  <li>Next Li Tag</li>
                  <li>Edit Detials</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            )}
          </TableCell>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

> Demo:- https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-https-jkp84?file=/src/App.js:0-1114

Comment: This worked , Thank you s much. was missing to pass the Id here.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you're not passing e in handleClick.
A way to do that is passing handleClick via Anonymous arrow function, so that you can reference it instead of invoking it.

```
<Button className = 'active-select-option'
           onClick = {()=>handleClick(e)}>Actions</Button>
```

Comment: no difference between onClick={handleClick} and onClick={e => handleClick(e)} (btw, in the second you missed e)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with your code but you can simplify a bit the `handleClick` method (there's no need to handle the `e.preventDefault()`) and also use the `&&` condition to display the `<div>`.
If `list` is `true` the `<div>` will be displayed, otherwise `false` is returned and the `<div>` is not displayed.

You can avoid to explicitly use the `list` variable with `setList(!list)` and instead use the value of the previous state provided as argument of the inner function of `setList(l => !l)`

If it's not going to work, could id be a css issue?

```
const [list, setList] = useState(false)

 const handleClick = () => {
        setList(l => !l);
    }

return (
   <TableCell>
      <Button className = 'active-select-option'
         onClick = {handleClick}>Actions</Button>
      {list &&                                                
         <div className = "select-option">
            <ul id = 'action1' className = "select-option-inner rounded">
                 <li>Buy More</li>
                 <li>Sell </li> 
                 <li>Next Li Tag</li> 
                 <li>Edit Detials</li>
            </ul> 
         </div>}
   </TableCell> )
```

Comment: The button click is happening but when i click on the button all the button in the table is being clicked

Comment: I don't understand, I assume that you are exporting this component into another one and displaying a table but the `list` state should be scoped and it should hide only the `<div>` in his specific component. Can you provide the code of the other components?